# THREE.js: Adding a line over extruded text

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to add a horizontal line over text which is then extruded:

```
var geo = new THREE.TextGeometry("x", geometry_options);
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0, side:THREE.DoubleSide});
geo.computeBoundingBox ();
var vec = new THREE.Shape();
vec.moveTo(geo.boundingBox.min.x, geo.boundingBox.max.y);
vec.lineTo(geo.boundingBox.max.x, geo.boundingBox.max.y);
geo.addShape(vec);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
```

A Javascript error occurs on calling geo.addShape(vec). I guess I have some misconception. I am not yet very familiar with THREE.js. Any help or an alternative way to accomplish that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `geo.addShape(vec);` try

geo.merge(vec.makeGeometry());

but your geometry is just a line -- it has no polygons -- so it probably won'ty look right.

an alternative might be to have two objects grouped together, one a mesh and the other a line, e.g.:

```
 var all = new THREE.Obejct3D();
 var geo = new THREE.TextGeometry("x", geometry_options);
 var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0, side:THREE.DoubleSide});
 geo.computeBoundingBox ();
 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
 all.add(mesh);
 var vecg = new THREE.Geometry();
 vecg.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3(geo.boundingBox.min.x, geo.boundingBox.max.y,0),
    new THREE.Vector3(geo.boundingBox.max.x, geo.boundingBox.max.y,0));
 var line = new THREE.Line(vecg, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial());
 all.add(line);
```

then `scene.add(all);` etc as needed

Comment: merging did not work, but I have used the idea of grouping and that works fine. Thanks bjorke!